# Get WebView controls for a View?

Tags: android, view, webview, zooming

After working with WebView for a while, and then moving back to standard Views, zooming and scrolling seems quite complicated. Are there any ways of using the same zoom and scrollcontrols for any View group, (builtInZoomControls, Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbar, Double tap to zoom out and pinch zooming) or are there any workarounds like an SDK or jar. file that will make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> zooming and scrolling seems quite complicated

Scrolling is a matter of using widgets that know how to scroll (e.g., `ListView`) or wrapping other widgets and containers in a `ScrollView` or `HorizontalScrollView`.

Zooming is not normally done except in fairly targeted circumstances (e.g., zooming an image, zooming a map).

> Are there any ways of using the same zoom and scrollcontrols for any View group

For "scrollcontrols", see above.

There are a few open source classes floating around for zooming an image. Zooming a map is built into `MapView`.